# President James A. Garfield and the Pythagorean proposition

Tags: reference-request, pythagorean-proposition

As some of you may recall, President James A. Garfield published at some point of his life a proof of the celebrated Pythagorean proposition.

I am interested in acquiring a pdf copy of President Garfield's paper containing  his proof. If I recall correctly, the journal it was published in is "The New England Journal of Education".

Does any of you happen to possess a copy of the said document or know where it is that one may obtain one?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: See the facsimile at [Mathematical Treasure: James A. Garfield's Proof of the Pythagorean Theorem](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-james-a-garfields-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem).